# Returning the years NOT recorded in database

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: Project type and Projects.

Table: Project type. Structure: type_id, type_name, year_start

Table: Project. Structure: project_id, type_id, year

Take an example: A project type with the name DDTT has been carried out every year since 2009. In the table project type, there is a row for this:

```
- type_id: 7, type_name: DDTT, year_start: 2009.
```

The details for each annual DDTT project has to be recorded separately. In the table projects there are 2 rows for DDTT 2010 and DDTT 2011.

```
- project_id: 9. type_id: 7, year: 2010
- project_id: 10. type_id: 7, year: 2011
```

Because DDTT has been carried out every year since 2009, DDTT 2009, and DDTT 2012 to DDTT 2015 have not been added to the projects table. To ensure that the users can only add the project that has not been added, in the Add Project interface they can only select DDTT 2009, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015.

Problem: How can I write the MySQL statement so that the result is the years not recorded in the database for each project type? Like: array(array(id:7, array(2009, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)), array(id:8, array(//some years))?

Also, the years returned must lie within the range from the project year start to the current year.

Comment: Have I understood it right - you need years for every project type, for which they are no records in the in project table?

Comment: Yes, and to be precise the years must also lie within the range from project year start to the current year. For example in the DDTT case, the years need be within the range 2009 to 2015.

Comment: You cannot select data that isn't there, but there are workarounds

Comment: Could you be so kind illuminating me how to one of those workarounds.